# How to prove - if an equation system has more variables than equations then it can't have a unique solution

Tags: linear-algebra

How do I prove the following claim:
"If an equation system has more variables than equations then it can't have a unique solution"
I know this is true, but how do I prove it? I can't use examples...

Comment: Matrices, you can use the fact that you cannot reduce it to the unit matrice but always get free variables.

Comment: it is easy to find a counter-example, e.g. $\sqrt{x}+ \sqrt{y} = 0$ is a system of one equation with two variables that admits the unique solution $x = y = 0$. The claim you quote is true for systems of linear equations, not necessarily for other types of systems.

Comment: @Imsteffan: Good point, but from context, I believe it is reasonable to assume that Lisa is considering a linear system of equations.

Comment: @MichaelJoyce Yes, the linearity assumption is reasonable, *and* I think it's also good to state it explicitly, but I didn't really believe the question had to do with non-linear systems....

Answer (score 3):

Hints:  If there are more variables (say you have $n$ of them) than equations (say you have $m$ of them), what can you say about the matrix of coefficients $A$?  What is the largest the rank of $A$ can be?  And what does that tell you about the dimension of the null space (also called kernel) of $A$?

If that terminology is unfamiliar, consider applying Gaussian elimination to $A$.  What is the maximal number of pivots you could obtain?  What does that tell you about how many free variables you will have?

Comment: I know the claim is true but I don't know what to write to prove it :(

Comment: Study the possible reduced row echelon forms the matrix $A$ could have and try to prove that there must always be a free variable.  (Why does that prove non-uniqueness?)