# What's happening when you have more variables than equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

This is probably a dumb question but I am confused about why you can simply choose any number for the free variables in a system of equations where you have more variables than equations. I can't wrap my head around it.

Comment: Related: [How to prove - if an equation system has more variables than equations then it can't have a unique solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1504948/how-to-prove-if-an-equation-system-has-more-variables-than-equations-then-it-c) and [Can an underdetermined system have a unique solution?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/207636/318073),...

Answer (score 1):

If $x_k$ are the variables, then best what you can achieve from a single equation is $x_k=\ldots$ where the variable $x_k$ doesn't occur on the right side. Then you can substitute all occurrences of $x_k$ by that result and obtain a system with one variable and one equation less. Repeating the process will leave you with a remaining set of variables and no more equations. Such variables are free and can be set to any value without changing the system at all.

However, the result $x_k=\ldots$ cannot always be obtained. E.g. if we have an equation $x_k^2=x_1+2x_2^3$ then we would have to take a square root, which isn't unambiguous anymore. Should we take the positive or the negative solution? So only in case our equations are linear we can do the simple addition "variables with equations plus free variables = all variables".